# Css and Html only Flag Banner

Tags: html, css

I have a website that needs a few css made banners and I'm having a bit of trouble creating them. I would show you what I had, but their too embarrassing to share...

My goal is to try and only use html and css to build these instead of images. This is kind of what I'm trying to build with the text inside of it...I think that is where I'm failing.

Any help would be much appreciated and would save my head the pain of hitting against the wall.

[image]

Comment: Start with this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-ribbon-with-borders

Comment: @KatieK Thank you for the link! I was looking at that, but my issue is that I need text on it and I doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: If the banners can't be posted here for some reason, then I suppose it would still be useful to post edited versions of them. It would at least give some indication of what the banners are supposed to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need is a `<div>` element and manipulate the CSS.

Have a look **[here](http://www.css3shapes.com/)** and **[here](http://themegamag.com/coding/css-coding/drawing-with-css3-tips/)** as they have everything that you will need to get started

I've also created a Fiddle for you that will give you the effect you want.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/vPCTE/)**

HTML

```
<div class="bookmarkRibbon"></div>
```

CSS

```
.bookmarkRibbon{
     width:0; 
     height:100px; 
     border-right:50px solid blue;
     border-left:50px solid blue;
     border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
}
```

And here is your flag with text inside as you show it in the picture.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/vPCTE/1/)**

HTML

```
<div class="ribbon">BANNER</div>
```

CSS

```
.ribbon {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#d00202;
}
.ribbon:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-width:30px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#d00202 #d00202 transparent #d00202;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have saved me many many hours! :)

Comment: If this solution doesn't fit your needs, you will need to follow a different way in resolving this. You will need 2 divs , 1 square and 1 triangle. Both will have the same width and the triangle will be positioned on the bottom of the square one. This will give you the same shape as final result and also you will have more options in adding text or even images inside your "flag" banner.

Comment: Fiddle links are dead.